# ploting barplot with multiple lables?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to plot bar-graph using R, which should look like this:

[image]

My data:

```
GO_term Category    Number  Percentage  Function
GO:0005623  Cellular Component  6   1.9 cell
GO:0043226  Cellular Component  5   1.6 organelle
GO:0044464  Cellular Component  6   1.9 cell part
GO:0044422  Cellular Component  2   0.6 organelle part
GO:0032991  Cellular Component  3   1   protein-containing complex
GO:0016020  Cellular Component  4   1.3 membrane
GO:0005576  Cellular Component  20  6.4 extracellular region
GO:0044425  Cellular Component  1   0.3 membrane part
GO:0005488  Molecular Function  104 33.2    binding
GO:0003824  Molecular Function  266 85  catalytic activity
GO:0005198  Molecular Function  3   1   structural molecule activity
GO:0045735  Molecular Function  3   1   nutrient reservoir activity
GO:0016209  Molecular Function  12  3.8 antioxidant activity
GO:0008152  Biological Process  189 60.4    metabolic process
GO:0009987  Biological Process  25  8   cellular process
GO:0051179  Biological Process  6   1.9 localization
GO:0050896  Biological Process  10  3.2 response to stimulus
GO:0051704  Biological Process  1   0.3 multi-organism process
GO:0071840  Biological Process  4   1.3 cellular component organization or biogenesis
```

I have tried using R:

```
> obs <- read.table("try.csv", sep = ",", header = T)

> barplot(obs$percentage, main = "gene ontology" , ylab = "Percentage",
    names.arg = c("cell", "organelle", "cell part ", "organelle part",
    "protein-containing complex", "membrane", "extracellular region",
    "membrane part", "binding", " catalytic activity", "structural molecule activity",
    "nutrient reservoir activity", "antioxidant activity", "metabolic process",
    "cellular process", "localization", "response to stimulus", " multi-organism process", 
    "cellular component organization or biogenesis"), 
    col = "darkred", las = 2)
```

which gave me:

[image]

I tried rotating my axis using :

```
> barplot(obs$percentage, col = "grey50", main = "gene ontology", ylab = "Number", 
    ylim = c(0,5+max(obs$number)), xlab = "try", names.arg = c("cell", "organelle",
    "cell part ", "organelle part", "protein-containing complex", "membrane",
    "extracellular region", "membrane part", "binding", " catalytic activity",
    "structural molecule activity", "nutrient reservoir activity", "antioxidant activity",
    "metabolic process", "cellular process", "localization", "response to stimulus",
    " multi-organism process", "cellular component organization or biogenesis"),
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size = rel (1.5))))
```

but it gave me the error:

> Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator In
>   addition: Warning message: In mean.default(width) : argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA

Then, I tried to cut the y-axis so that my data look clean by using:

```
> gap.barplot(obs$percentage, main = "gene ontology", ylab = "Percentage",
    ylim = c(0,5+max(obs$number)), xlab = "try", names.arg = c("cell", "organelle",
    "cell part ", "organelle part", "protein-containing complex", "membrane",
    "extracellular region", "membrane part", "binding", " catalytic activity",
    "structural molecule activity", "nutrient reservoir activity", "antioxidant activity",
    "metabolic process", "cellular process", "localization", "response to stimulus",
    " multi-organism process", "cellular component organization or biogenesis"),
    las = 2,  col = "darkred", gap=c(10, 30), ytics = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 80, 90, 100))
```

Output:

[image]

`>dput(obs)` output:

```
structure(list(GO_term = structure(c(5L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 
8L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 19L), .Label = c("GO:0003824", 
"GO:0005198", "GO:0005488", "GO:0005576", "GO:0005623", "GO:0008152", 
"GO:0009987", "GO:0016020", "GO:0016209", "GO:0032991", "GO:0043226", 
"GO:0044422", "GO:0044425", "GO:0044464", "GO:0045735", "GO:0050896", 
"GO:0051179", "GO:0051704", "GO:0071840"), class = "factor"), 
    Category = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Biological Process", 
    "Cellular Component", "Molecular Function"), class = "factor"), 
    Number = c(6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 20L, 1L, 104L, 266L, 3L, 
    3L, 12L, 189L, 25L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 4L), Percentage = c(1.9, 
    1.6, 1.9, 0.6, 1, 1.3, 6.4, 0.3, 33.2, 85, 1, 1, 3.8, 60.4, 
    8, 1.9, 3.2, 0.3, 1.3), Function = structure(1:19, .Label = c("cell", 
    "organelle", "cell part", "organelle part", "protein-containing complex", 
    "membrane", "extracellular region", "membrane part", "binding", 
    "catalytic activity", "structural molecule activity", "nutrient reservoir activity", 
    "antioxidant activity", "metabolic process", "cellular process", 
    "localization", "response to stimulus", "multi-organism process", 
    "cellular component organization or biogenesis"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am not able to troubleshoot the problem nor able to add dual y-axis and axis-break.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Here is the base-plot solution.

1.To **fit all the axis labels** to the plot you may specify the plot margins to fit all the axis labels. Probably, it makes sense to adapt the bottom margin according to the maximum labels length:

```
# a coefficient to transfer a label width to a margin width
tx_width_expansion <- 0.3
# define the plot margins
par(mar = c(tx_width_expansion * (max(nchar(obs$Function))), 4, 4, 5))
barplot(heigh = obs$Percentage, main = "gene ontology" , ylab = "Percentage",
    names.arg = obs$Function,
    col = "darkred", las = 2, plot = TRUE)
```

The results is

[image: plot_1]

2.If you want to **rotate the labels**, it is slightly more complicated in the base plot as compared with ggplot2:

```
x <- barplot(heigh = obs$Percentage, main = "gene ontology" , ylab = "Percentage",
    col = "darkred", las = 2, plot = TRUE)
text(cex = 1 , x = x - .25, y = -2.25, obs$Function, 
    xpd = TRUE, adj = 1, srt = 45)
```

[image: plot_2]

3.Finally, you you really **need the second axis**, it may be done by drawing the second plot over the first one

```
par(new = TRUE)
barplot(heigh = 100 * obs$Percentage, main = "gene ontology" , ylab = "",
    axes = FALSE, col = "darkred")
mtext("Number of genes", side = 4, line = 3) 
axis(4, las = 1)
```

[image]

However, note please that the second axis is safe only if the second-axis data were obtained by a transformation of the first-axis data. Otherwise the result may be misleading. That is why I have used `100 * obs$Percentage` in the third code chunk instead of `100 * obs$Number` data.

Comment: Thank you for the cooperation, but when I applied your codes to my data it gave me the error:  `> par(mar = c(tx_width_expansion * (max(nchar(obs$Function))), 4, 4, 5))` error:  `Error in obs$category : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: That means, that something is wrong with the data structure. Could you please show the output of `dput(obs)`?

Comment: I have shortened my output as it was exceeding the limit.

Comment: You may include the output in you question. Actually, using `dput()`  is good practice to ensure reproducibility of your input data.

Comment: I have solved the error, now my graph is going outside the chart area. image: [https://ibb.co/yFKZfS2], also the second y-axis is the number of genes (Total genes= 313 i.e 100 at first y-axis should be 313 at the second axis).

Comment: image:  ibb.co/yFKZfS2

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! Note please, that the `Category` and `Function` columns are of factor type, which make difficult its' use for labeling. It may be a good idea to transform them to characters (e.g. `obs$Function <- as.character(obs$Function)`). As for the chart area, if the problem is the cutting of x-labels, you may solve it playing with the `tx_width_expansion` value.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your codes, but now my problem is to add axis break and adding obs$Category label on X-axis.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier for people to help if you provide the data frame like this:

```
obs <- data.frame(
  GOTerm=c("GO:0005623", "GO0043226", "GO:005488"),
  Category=c("Cellular Component", "Cellular Component", "Molecular Function"),
  Number=c(6,5,104),
  Percentage=c(1.9, 1.6, 33.2),
  Function=c("cell", "organelle", "binding")
)
```

First I would re-level the Function-column so that you can use it directly in the plots instead of writing the individual GOterm-titles manually (which is also error-prone). By re-leveling, the order of the columns is not changed due to alphabetical reasons anymore:

```
obs$Function <- factor(obs$Function, levels=obs$Function)
```

To the barplot issue: You misspelled the column names (obs$percentage instead of obs$Percentage), which will be an issue. But even then, it had problems generating the graph.
It might be easiest to just use ggplot instead:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_bar (data=obs, aes(x=Function, y=Percentage), stat="identity", fill="darkred", color="black") + #base graph
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100), #limits the y axis
                     expand = c(0,0)) + #starts the y axis at 0
  theme_classic() + #basic theme
  theme( #extended theme options
    axis.title.x=element_blank(), #remove the x-axis title
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1) #rotate x-axis text (hjust is for horizontal leveling)
    )
```

[image: ggplot-barplot]

For the gap-plot, also here you misspelled column names. Also, I think in the ylim you don't want to use max(obs$Number) but rather max(obs$Percentage), as your y axis stems from obs$Percentage. For some reason gap-barplot still seems to double the y-limit, so just half it. The red color here must be given as many times as there are columns, solveable by a rep("darkred", nrow(obs)).

```
library(plotrix)
gap.barplot(y=obs$Percentage,
            xaxlab=obs$Function,
            gap=c(10,20),
            col = rep("darkred",nrow(obs)),
            main="gene ontology",
            xlab = "try",
            ylab="Percentage",
            ylim=c(0, (0.5*(5+max(obs$Percentage)))),
            ytics=c(0,10,20,370,40,80,90,100),
            las=2
            )
```

[image: gap.barplot]

Comment: `ytics` is not clear in the axis-break graph representing only 20%.